# A basic question on intuition of second countability for definition of topological manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

What is the intuition behind the requirement of second countability in definition of topological manifold? It seems that it is relevant to the $\mathbb{R}^n$ has second countable basis. Is there any other reason for why it has to include the second countability?

Comment: It is merely to limit how "large" the spaces can be. See for instance the [long line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)), which is _not_ second countable.

Comment: Presumably it is also to ensure that they can embedded into $R^m$, for large enough $m$.

Comment: You also need second countability for countable partitions of unity.